# Unity Compiler Error (EditorWindowWrapper)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, editor

I have compiler errors when i try to build my project. I haven't seen anyone with the same problems that's why i'm writing it here.

This is the main error

```
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.visualscripting@1.7.6\Editor\VisualScripting.Core\Windows\EditorWindowWrapper.cs(10,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'WrappedEditorWindow' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This is a vanilla Unity C# project with nothing added to it. When i try and make another project it still gives the same error.

It will only allow me to see the project in Safe Mode

[Here is a screenshot of Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htBPH.png)

Does anyone know the problem or how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the vs compiler is normal. There is a way: open "Window" > "package Manager", then press the + (plus sign) in the upper left corner of the pop-up window: Add Package from git URL, enter com.unity.multiplayer- in the text box shown below the plus sign hlapi. The add button on the right side of the text box will light up, click Install, and the error will be resolved after the installation is complete.